# ArcGIS .Net SDK publish shapefile to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, .net

I am quite new with ArcGIS Online and their .Net SDK.
I am trying to load shapefile into my ArcGIS online account using .Net SDK.
On the ESRI tutorial portal, there is 0 information about it, all is focused around WPF technology.
[image]

From what I heard, the Esri .Net SDK have complete integration with ArcGIS Online portal, but I cannot find any documentation of how to use this SDK with Online server. Did anyone manage to actually do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently is not that hard to do.

ESRI provided another guide documents for .Net SDK [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/forms/guide/add-items-to-a-portal.htm)

Following their tutorial simply shp import will look as follow:

```
    public async Task PublishShp()
    {
        // All shp files needs to be pack into ZIP
        const string filePath = "C://test.zip";
        const string portalFileName = "test";
        var organizationUri = new Uri("https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/");

        // Create credential token
        var cred = await AuthenticationManager.Current.GenerateCredentialAsync(
            organizationUri,
            _userName,
            _password) as ArcGISTokenCredential;

        // connect to the portal, pass in the token 
        var portal = await ArcGISPortal.CreateAsync(
            organizationUri,
            cred,
            CancellationToken.None);

        // Create portal item object
        var item = new PortalItem(portal, PortalItemType.ShapeFile, portalFileName);

        // All shp files into be zip into single file
        var data = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        var content = new PortalItemContentParameters(data, portalFileName, mediaType);
        await portal.User.AddPortalItemAsync(item, content);
        data.Close();
    }
```